# Send private message in TEAMS from Python

Tags: python

I would like to send a private message in TEAMS with python, I developed it to send a message to channel group with webhook, but now I would like to send a private message to a user.

Can I do this with the Teams API or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

So far I've had to research this and there isn't much information.